# Embeddings and discrete spaces.

Tags: general-topology

The next is a problem in the context of $0$-dimensional Hausdorff spaces.

If $S$ is a subspace of a space $X$ such that for every continuous function with domain $S$ and codomain the discrete space of two points we may extend that function to a continuous function with domain $X$ and codomain the same discrete set, then we say that $S$ is a $2$ embedding, if we change $2$ for $3$ in the previous definition then obtain the definition of $3$ embedding. The question is, in fact, if both conditions are equivalent, clearly $3$ embedding implies $2$ embedding, but the converse is true?

Thank you for the further answers.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that all finite-embeddings ($\ge 2$) are equivalent. The condition of $S$ being $2$-embedded to $X$ can be reformulated as follows: Any decomposition of $S$ to $2$ summands ($2$ disjoint clopen subspaces of $S$ covering $S$) can be extended to such decomposition of $X$. The same for $n$-embedding. Now if you want to extend $3$-decomposition A + B + C and can extend only $2$-decompositions, you can first extend $A + (B + C)$ to $A' + (B + C)'$ and then extend $(A + B) + C$ to $(A + B)' + C'$. Now the extension of $A + B + C$ is $$A' + \Big((B + C)' ∩ (A + B)'\Big) + \Big((B + C)' ∩ C'\Big)\;.$$ Similar procedure can be done for any finite $n$.

Comment: OK thank you very much for the answer and for the reformulation of the given condition.