# Embeddings and intersection of clopen subsets

Tags: general-topology, dimension-theory-analysis

My new question is again in the context of Hausdorff 0-dimensional spaces.

We say that S subspace of a space X is a 2-embedding if for every continuous function with domain S and codomain 2(the discrete space of two points) there is a continuous extension for the function defined in the total space and codomain 2, and if we put $\mathbb{N}$ instead 2 we obtain the definition of $\mathbb{N}$-embedding.

Then the problem is this: Let S a 2 embedding of a space X. Then S is a $\mathbb{N}$-embedding if and only if for every F such that is disjoint with S and is the intersection of a countable family of clopen subsets of X, there exist a clopen subset T of X such that $F\subseteq T$ and $S\subseteq X/T$.

Thank you for the further answers.

Answer (score 0):

We can use the same reformulation as in [Embeddings and discrete spaces.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/483757/embeddings-and-discrete-spaces/) A continuous function $f: X \to \mathbb{N}$ is actually the same thing as clopen decomposition of $X$ indexed by $\mathbb{N}$. If you have $f$ you can take $\{C_i = f^{-1}[\{i\}]: i ∈ \mathbb{N}\}$. If you have $\{C_i: i ∈ \mathbb{N}\}$ you can define $f$ so that $f$ takes value $i$ on $C_i$.

For one implication, we start with a decomposition of $S$ into countable clopen subspaces $\{C_i: i < ω\}$. And we want to extend this decomposition to clopen decomposition of whole $X$. Because $S$ is $2$-embedded we can find for any $i$ a clopen subset of $X$ $C'_i$ such that $C'_i ∩ S = C_i$. Now we have decomposition of $X$ into sets $\{D_i = C'_i ∩ \bigcap_{j < i} (X \setminus C'_j): i < ω\}$ and $D_ω = \bigcap_{j < ω} (X \setminus C'_j)$. But the last set $D_ω$ is not necessarily clopen which is our last obstacle. However it is disjoint with $S$ and is a countable intersection of clopens so we can use the second assumption and find that clopen $T$ which separates $S$ from $D_ω$. Now the extended decomposition of $X$ which we are looking for is made of $D_i ∩ T$ for $i < ω$ and $X \setminus T$. It is actually made of one more element that the original decomposition of $S$ but it doesn't matter since we can add this extra component $X \setminus T$ to any other component.

I don't know how to prove the other implication. We have $\{C_i: i < ω\}$ clopen subsets in $X$ such that $S ∩ C = ∅$ where $C = \bigcap_{i < ω} C_i$ and we want to conclude that $S$ can be clopenly separated from $C$ under assumption that $S$ is $\mathbb{N}$-embedded into $X$. Let's take $\{\bigcap_{j < i} C_j ∩ (X \setminus C_i) ∩ S: i < ω\}$ which is by assumption clopen decomposition of $S$. By the assumption this can be extended to clopen decomposition of $X$. If $C$ intersected only finite number of components of this decomposition (which it would if $X$ was countably compact) than one could take their union intersected with enought sets $C_i$.

Also note that for countably compact $C$ can be clopenly separated from any countable intersection of clopen sets, so countably compact $2$-embedded subspace is $\mathbb{N}$-embedded.

Comment: OK, thank you, but in the first implication the extension given is a extension of the initials Ci´s? I don´t see that clearly, sorry.

Comment: @user78594: Yes that's why it is called by $C'_i$s and it is also implied by the condition $C'_i ∩ S = C_i$.

Comment: Hello, finally I get it, thank you very much, for the first implication, we can say anything about the series of the character functions of the complements of the Ci's? If the series is continuous(restricted in S), we have a extension in all the space, this function works? In fact, we can suppose that the family is decreasing, but I don't know if the function really is well defined and continuous in that case...

Comment: @user78594 Actually there was a serious typo in the proof (forgot to complement some sets so it didn't make sense). I've fixed it and added explanation on relation between the functions and decompositions. I'm not sure what is the series you are talking about and what do you mean by the series being continuous.

Comment: OK, if the space intersect only a finite number of Ci's or if S is compact then the problem is solved, but for the not compact case, we have a open cover of S without a finite subcover, this cover can help in the proof?

Comment: @user78594: Still don't know how to prove the second implication. But it can be shown (under assumption of $\mathbb{N}$-embedding) that the closure of $S$ is disjoint with the countable intersection of clopens. So it holds also for $X$ strongly zero dimenstional (specially for $X$ zero dimensional and Lindelöf).